# Converting Matlab/C function into version without sourcecode

Tags: c, matlab

Im totally new to Matlab. How can I convert a simple Matlab/C function INTO a version that can be run in Matlab WITHOUT showing the source code?? Please help!

Comment: Could you please clarify the question. What do you mean by a "simple Matlab/C function". Do you have [pcode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html) and a C executable? a [mex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html)? Why can you not look at the source code?

Comment: @Raab70 I was given a task to convert a simple quadratic fucntion:
'
function y=myquadratic(x,c)
% x must be a vector in matlab, and c a scalar.
% Both can be scalars for the c program (to keep things as simple as possible)
y=c*x.^2;
return
'
into a version that can be distributed to other matlab users to use/execute within Matlab, but without sharing the source code. I honestly do not know anything. Is using a compiler the right way?
Thank you!

Comment: So you have the source code, and you want to create a distributable version which will not show your source code to others? If this is the case then the pcode link should be what you're looking for on the matlab side. The C code will need to be compiled into an executable.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for asking. The above function was indeed a matlab function. However, the task was to convert this function AND the c-function that does the same (i.e. give y= c*x^2) into, as mentioned above, a distributable version.

Comment: @Raab70, thank you for replying. Can you elaborate on the use of the pcode? Regarding the C function, if i convert that into an executable, would it be able to run in Matlab?THANK YOU!

Comment: A C executable would be run from the command line. The only way to run C code in matlab is the above mentioned mex files which uses the [Mex-API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-files-1.html). I have never personally used this functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Raab70! I will post another question about this and keep the Mex-API in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your clarification the answer you're looking for is  the often forgotten matlab [pcode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html).

pcode is a great tool which allows you to distribute matlab code, without giving up the secrets of your source code (m-file). pcode files can ONLY be created on functions. So if you wrote a simple function:

```
function [y] = myfunction(x)
y=x.^2;
end
```

Then you could create a pcode file from this with the matlab command :

```
pcode('myfunction');
```

you would then have a `myfunction.m` and a protected `myfunction.p`.

There is a plethora of online documentation of people trying (unsuccesfully) to translate pcode back to an m-file.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/272505

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9848-how-to-decrypt-a-pcode

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/75012-pcode-obfuscation-cracked-alternatives

As for compiling your C-code, I am not an expert in that area but there are many tools to do so. I personally tend to use [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Any further questions about compiling C-code should probably be opened as a new question, or search for some tutorials on getting started with C.

Comment: +1 for finding a semi-respectable usage of the word `plethora` while posting on a technical site.  (i.e. as opposed to the commonly used `lots`, `tons`, `many`...)

Comment: Only semi-respactable! :(